# Neo4j: How to speedup while creating unique nodes in BatchInserter

Tags: neo4j

I need to create millions of nodes out of which a number of nodes should be unique. I am using BatchInserter for inserting nodes. Due to uniqueness constraint I need to nodeIndex.flush() a number of times because of which it's time consuming.
Any guidance how I can speed-up this activity is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nodeIndex.flush() consumes lot of time. I am now checking unique constraint by saving nodes details in my Set instead of doing the costly operation of doing nodeIndex.flush() and then checking for presence of node by nodeIndex.query()